# is "can only but" a real English expression?

Tags: grammar

I am a native Enlgish speaker and this expression sounds natural to me (somehow), but I am aware it seems very grammatically invalid. I think I read it somewhere before and it has bothered me for a while, it sounds correct in my ears!

For example, "The milk is good, which only but increases the quality of the ice cream"

To me, it sounds like the combination "only but" is an extra emphasis.

I am probably crazy and everyone else thinks this combination is ridiculous and makes no sense.

Comment: Your example is wrong and doesn’t match what you’ve got in the title (which is correct). The correct example should be: *The milk is good, which can but only increase the quality of the ice cream.*

Comment: @Jim I think you've spotted the problem the OP has which is that the idiomatic expression is "...can but only..." while the expression in the question is "...can only but.." which is not, I feel, idiomatic.

Comment: Ok thanks, I feel equally for both but the second opinions makes it clear that it should be "can but only". I still welcome a proper answer explaining how this makes sense, its proper use, and its etymology.

Answer (score 3):

*Only but* means *only* or *nothing but*.

Here is ***only but*** under ***only*** in the OED:

> **PHRASES
> P2.** ***only but*** (also ***but only***):  *(a)* only, merely;  *(b)* except only. Now *poetic*.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford
> English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Below are some [*only but* examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100367676). Swap in *only* or *nothing but* for *only but* to see:

> *Ultimately, there is only but one choice for you, no? To consume the entire pint.*
>  <sub>TV *The Boys*</sub>

> *Father! I said aloud into the waters. To see you here! Even if it is only but a dream!*
>  <sub>FIC *Michigan Quarterly Review*</sub>

> *But I think, long term . . . it can only but perhaps stoke the fires of inflation longer term.*
>  <sub>SPOK *PBS NewsHour*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between your title and the example you give.

"The milk is good, which can only but increase the quality of the ice cream" would be fine.